# Making sense of nulls in BigQuery array

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I constantly find myself converting a column to an array. Here is an example:

```
`cost`
4.50
null
1.00
```

And the correspond array would be:

```
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(val) FROM tbl
```

This should give me `[4.50, null, 1.00]` but of course since BigQuery arrays don't support `null`, it produces an error. Is there any workaround for working with `null`s in an array, or an open feature request for this? Yes I can 'ignore nulls' and get `[4.50, 1.00]` but then that loses information that I need and so I cannot match it up with other columns in something like a zip or other operation so it's not a possibility. Example from Postgres of how it should be handled:

```
postgres=# SELECT ARRAY_AGG(cost) FROM (VALUES (4.50),(null),(1.00)) tbl(cost);
    array_agg     
------------------
 {4.50,NULL,1.00}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible workaround is to wrap it in a `struct`, such as:

```
with tbl as (
 select 4.50 val union all
 select null union all
 select 1.00 
)
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(val)) FROM tbl
```

[image]

(But really if this can be done, why doesn't BigQuery implicitly do this and then they can support `null`s 'natively'?)